# CKEditor Integration

Tags: ee2, wysiwyg, ckeditor

i was searching for a while, but my Google-fu probably isn't strong enough to find out, how to create a CKEditor Fieldtype, or find any plugin, that will do that for me. So what am i asking for? **Does anybody know any EE2 compatible plugin, that will give me a CKEditor Fieldtype (Preferably free one)?**

And additional question, is there any possibility to create new content and edit it using frontend forms (so moderators don't need to go to CP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three commercial EE add-ons which use CKEditor - all very affordable:

- [Wygwam](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam)
- [Expresso](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/expresso)
- [Wyvern](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wyvern)

And yes, you can add/edit entries via a front-end form, using the included [Channel Form module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/).

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The free alternative to CKEditor plugin is making a front-end, more user friendly administration using the [Channel Form Module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/) and just using the CKEditor as you would normally!